# model training time becomes slower after break accidently

Tags: python, pytorch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NlDD.jpg)
I'm trying to a video-vit model with pytorch and a 3090 GPU(24G) on a SSD.I choose batchsize of 64 and num_workes of 14.
At the beginging the training time was 7 hours per epoch which is fine.However after breaking the train progress accidently (like power off),the traing time became 9hours with the last-checkpoint.That's so weird.I find that the GPU memory was 23.5G and temperature was a little higher when training time is 7 hours. But now is 23.0G and lower temperature. The GPU utilization is almost 100%。When I try training on another 3090,same situation happens if I break progress with ctrl+c.
So please help me out this.

I change different SSD and reinstall vscode .Didn't help.
Only training on a different computer with GPU  worked  faster.But training time became slower if
I break and continue training progress.

Comment: perhaps provide a minimal functional version of your training loop for someone to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenGVLab/unmasked_teacher/tree/main
I alomst borrow UnmaskedTeacher-single modality branch 's code.

Comment: it would be better to raise this as an issue on the repo. Alternatively, providing a minimal working example would be helpful. A tip: you may check of you are using distributed training in both cases or not.